# Using Hibernate batching with JPA Datasource

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is a theoretical question.  When using the Hibernate batching mechanism to insert rows does the failure of one row in a batch trigger the rollback of all rows that were submitting in the request?

Example:  Given a collection of customer objects (total of 100)  where all have unique primary key values, except one which is a duplicate value.

Given the Hibernate batching property is set:
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 100

When datasource addOrUpdate method is called with the collection of customers fails with the error for the duplicated value, are all the rows that where inserted prior to the error rolled back or committed?   No explicate transaction management is performed by the application.

I have search both Hibernate and Spring JPA information but have not found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the transaction boundary that you define. If you save all 100 customers in the same transaction , any of failed customer will cause all customers to rollback.

Assuming you are using Spring Data JPA repository and do not define the transaction boundary explicitly (i.e using `@Transactional`) , by default calling `save()` / `saveAll()` / `saveAndFlush()` etc. on the `JpaRepository` will execute in their own transaction.

So if you use `saveAll()` to save 100 customers , any of failed customer will cause all customers to rollback.

On the other hand , if you use `save()` for each customer one by one. Whether a customer fail or not will not affect the others as they are execute in the separate transaction. *(P.S. But JDBC batching feature will not be enabled in such case since it does not batch multiple customers to be saved in a single transaction.)*